# ScrollMagic - Tween - Text fade-in and fade-out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I'm trying to use ScrollMagic.js on my website to reveal text paragraphs. My script already can fade the text, but I would like to create something as pause while the text fading-in and once the effect would finish, the scroll is gonna continue. Something like that is on official [website](http://scrollmagic.io/). The whole page scrolling down after the effect on the heading passed.

Can someone help me how to rewrite it, so scroll will wait until the whole animation is over? I'm planing to do more animations and the effect would be better.

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768) {
      // init controller
      var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
      // Fade in
      var fadeInTimeline = new TimelineMax();
      var fadeInFrom = TweenMax.from("#opacity", 1, {
        autoAlpha: 0
      });
      var fadeInTo = TweenMax.to("#opacity", 1, {
        autoAlpha: 1
      });
      fadeInTimeline
        .add(fadeInFrom)
        .add(fadeInTo);

      new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: "#slidein2",
          offset: 200,
        })
        .setTween(fadeInTimeline)
        .duration(400)
        .addTo(controller);

      //Fly in from the left
      var fromBottomTimeline = new TimelineMax();
      var fromBottomFrom = TweenMax.from("#bottom", 1, {
        y: 300
      });
      var fromBottomTo = TweenMax.to("#bottom", 1, {
        y: 0
      });
      fromBottomTimeline
        .add(fromBottomFrom)
        .add(fromBottomTo);

      new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: "#slidein2",
          offset: 200,
        })
        .setTween(fromBottomTimeline)
        .duration(400)
        .addTo(controller);

    }

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

```css
.blabler {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin: 5rem 15rem !important;
  line-height: 60pt;
  text-justify:inter-word;
  font-family: 'Metrophobic', sans-serif;

}

.blabler .right {
text-align: right;
}

.blabler .center {
text-align: center;
text-justify:inter-character;
}

.blabler .left {
text-align: left;
text-justify:inter-character;
}
body {
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metrophobic|PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/jquery.ScrollMagic.js"></script>


  <div id="slidein2" class="row blabler">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="center-align">
        <span id="left" class="left textf">Nulla quis diam. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a.</span>
        <span class="right textf">Nulla quis diam. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a.</span>
        <span id="opacity" class="center textf">Nulla quis diam. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a.</span>
        <span class="right textf">Nulla quis diam. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a.</span>
        <span id="bottom" class="center textf">Nulla quis diam. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a.</span>
        <span class="right textf">Nulla quis diam. Sed elit dui, pellentesque a.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ScrollMagic does not wait for the animation to complete. Instead what it is doing is pinning the `start` section to the top of the page i.e. setting position to fixed.

```
// container pin
var startpin = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 700
 })
 .setPin("section#start")
 .addTo(controller);
```

This is the code on the demo page. It keeps the start div in position for the first 700 px worth of scroll.

You could also do this using the [`end`](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#event:end) event to release the position.

Comment: I tried that... as I tried many examples before... but I couldn't get it working, because I need to more than one animation on the page in that specific section.

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle of your current version?

Comment: I posted the current version , but... that's all what I have... The fade works as it should in this situation, but just for one span and the scrolling is not pausing.

Comment: Okay, So I tried to do some progress and I fixeed the fiddle, so It should work now. I don't know why at least the fade doesn't work here, when on my computer does....